# Regex to exclude something

Tags: php, regex

This is my Regex to fetch all tags with class:

```
preg_match_all('/<\s*\w*\s*class\s*=\s*"?\s*([\w\s%#\/\.;:_-]*)\s*"?.*?>/',file,$matches);
```

It matches all tags with class like `<a class="abc">`

The problem is that if any tag contains extra attribute before class than this Regex are unable to get it.

E.g.: `<a id="fig_3_1" class="figure-contents">`

I want `<a class="figure-contents">` by ignore fig_3_1

Any idea to exclude it?

Comment: Use an HTML parser, not regex.

Answer (score 0):

```
<\s*\w*.*?\s*class\s*=\s*"?\s*([\w\s%#\/\.;:_-]*)\s*"?.*?>
```

Probably this works
but you better use simple_html_dom

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this amazing SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2030635) and reconsider.

You will most likely be better of using a html parser instead. You can do so using the [DOM](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) model.

A simple sample of how it *can* be used below.

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$images = $dom->getElementsByTagName('img');
foreach ($images as $image) {
    $image->setAttribute('src', 'http://example.com/' .$image->getAttribute('src'));
}
$html = $dom->saveHTML();
```